# How to use elements from a second list within lapply()

Tags: r, lapply

I have two lists, for example:

```
L1 <- list(A=1:3, B=4:6)
L2 <- list(A=2, B=3)
```

and I want the elements of the first list to be repeated by the numers in the second list, resulting in:

```
>L3
$A
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3

$B
[1] 4 5 6 4 5 6 4 5 6
```

I tried with `lapply()` but I cannot figure out the right times argument:

```
L3 <- lapply(L1, function(x) rep(x, L2))
```

Certainly quite easy to solve, but I don't get it right now.

Comment: ... Simply ```Map(`rep`, L1, L2)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
lapply(names(L1), function(x) rep(L1[[x]], L2[[x]]))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Quite easy, as I said. Thank you very much!